# What's wrong when making gcc 4.9.1?

Tags: gcc, makefile, installation

In the newest gcc 4.9.1 package, after ./configure I ran make, and it failed with error message:

```
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... /root/tar/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/root/tar/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include   
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/root/tar/gcc-4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I checked the config.log in the  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc/, and it said,

```
configure:3389: /root/tar/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/root/tar/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
/root/tar/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
configure:3392: $? = 1
configure:3580: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3602: /root/tar/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/root/tar/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include    -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
/root/tar/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
configure:3606: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
```

But obviously I have libmpc.so.2 in /usr/local/lib. What's wrong??

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Configuration_fails_with_.27.27configure:_error:_cannot_compute_suffix_of_object_files:_cannot_compile.27.27._What_is_the_problem.3F

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is due to the fact that the default path /usr/local/lib is not included in the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. Sorry for this stupid question...

Comment: You can delete a question if you don't think it'll be useful for others.